# Permission error when try to install psycopg2 on Mac with "pip install psycopg2"

Tags: psycopg2

When I try to install psycopg2 on Mac with "pip install psycopg2", I got permission error. The following is the capture:

Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
  Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    / A p p l i c a t i o n s / X c o d e . a p p / C o n t e n t s / D e v e l o p e r / T o o l c h a i n s / X c o d e D e f a u l t . x c t o o l c h a i n / u s r / b i n / c l a n g   - f n o - s t r i c t - a l i a s i n g   - f n o - c o m m o n   - d y n a m i c     - a r c h   i 3 8 6   - a r c h   x 8 6 _ 6 4   - g   - O 2   - D N D E B U G   - g   - O 3   -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090105 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    unable to execute /: Permission denied
    error: command '/' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /Users/ivy.jia@canarie.local/venv/python_venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;**file**='/Users/ivy.jia@canarie.local/venv/python_venv/build/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-O7Ov2u-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/ivy.jia@canarie.local/venv/python_venv/bin/../include/site/python2.7:
    running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension

/ A p p l i c a t i o n s / X c o d e . a p p / C o n t e n t s / D e v e l o p e r / T o o l c h a i n s / X c o d e D e f a u l t . x c t o o l c h a i n / u s r / b i n / c l a n g   - f n o - s t r i c t - a l i a s i n g   - f n o - c o m m o n   - d y n a m i c     - a r c h   i 3 8 6   - a r c h   x 8 6 _ 6 4   - g   - O 2   - D N D E B U G   - g   - O 3   -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5.1 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090105 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o

unable to execute /: Permission denied

error: command '/' failed with exit status

Answer (score 2):

For a variety of packages that require c compilation (gevent, zeromq, etc.) it seems that pip is adding extra spaces to the command, causing it to fail:

go into Xcode and explicitly download the Command Line Tools (under Preferences > Downloads).

From:
http://www.pressingquestion.com/5111217/Pip-Installation-Adds-Extra-Spaces-To-Command-On-Os-X-108

Comment: Yes, this works for me. This prefixes the compile line with the cc compiler: 
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes ...